# XNA Fails To Draw Model On Screen Because It Thinks It Contains No Meshes

Tags: c#, xna, blender, mesh

I created this simple rectangle model in Blender that is textured (1024 x 1024). I loaded the model in XNA and it does not display on the screen. I breakpointed on the model and the debug screen says it contains zero meshes which is not true, because I opened the model in Blender and it shows the mesh. There is a total of 1 meshes. What could be wrong? Is it the code? Or is it Blender? I am new to 3D modeling. Here is the source code below:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            paddelloader1.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ballpos);
            paddelloader1.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);
            paddelloader1.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), 800f / 480f, 0.1f, 100f);
            paddelloader1.Load();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

Comment: You might have more chances to get an answer on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Daniel: What does `paddelloader1.Load()` do?  Can you post the code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by re-exporting the model in Blender and it fixed the problem.